# gnuplot x label position in histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

i have the following data:

```
t_4 24 3 0 0
t_6 37 4 0 0
t_8 51 4 2 0 

t_4 15 1 0 0
t_6 21 0 0 1
t_8 30 0 0 1

t_4 13 2 1 0
t_6 20 3 1 0
t_8 22 4 1 0
```

and i try to make an histogram similar to this http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/gnuplot/stack+cluster.dem , with this modify version of the code:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5
set key invert samplen 0.2
set key samplen 0.2
set bmargin 3
set offset 0,2,0,0

set title "number of multiple resonances"

plot newhistogram "1:j" lt 1, \
     'stack+cluster.dat' index 0 u 2:xtic(1) title "one", \
     '' index 0 u 3 title "two", \
     '' index 0 u 4 title "three", \
     '' index 0 u 5 title "four"

     newhistogram "2:j" lt 1, \
     'stack+cluster.dat' index 1 u 2:xtic(1) notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 3 notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 4 notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 5 notitle

      newhistogram "3:j" lt 1, \
     'stack+cluster.dat' index 1 u 2:xtic(1) notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 3 notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 4 notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 5 notitle
```

but this is the output i found [image]

As you can see the problem is in the x labels names `newhistogram "1:j"` , `"2:j"` and `"3:j"` : i can see only "1:j" and overlapped with the "t_4...".

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That script gives an error! All commands must belong to a single `plot` commands. As you have it, the script terminates before the second `newhistogram`.

The next thing is, that you need to separate two blocks with *two* blank lines in order to address them with the `index` parameter (for this see also the comments in the data file http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/gnuplot/stack+cluster.dat which belongs to the example you talked about).

With these corrections you get the following script (note also the `title offset`):

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked title offset 0,-1
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5
set key invert samplen 0.2
set key samplen 0.2
set bmargin 3
set offset 0,2,0,0

set title "number of multiple resonances"

plot newhistogram "1:j" lt 1, \
     'stack+cluster.dat' index 0 u 2:xtic(1) title "one", \
     '' index 0 u 3 title "two", \
     '' index 0 u 4 title "three", \
     '' index 0 u 5 title "four",\
     newhistogram "2:j" lt 1, \
     'stack+cluster.dat' index 1 u 2:xtic(1) notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 3 notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 4 notitle, \
     '' index 1 u 5 notitle,\
      newhistogram "3:j" lt 1, \
     'stack+cluster.dat' index 1 u 2:xtic(1) notitle, \
     '' index 2 u 3 notitle, \
     '' index 2 u 4 notitle, \
     '' index 2 u 5 notitle
```

with the result (with 4.6.5):

[image]

Comment: It was not clear for me at a first glance.  The magic is in the line: **set style histogram rowstacked title offset 0,-1**