# gnuplot newhistogram: how to set titles font size?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot 4.4.3 to plot some histograms.

My question is very similar to this one:
[gnuplot-x-label-position-in-histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867487/gnuplot-x-label-position-in-histogram)

But I want to make the newhistogram titles larger.
By newhistogram titles I mean those below the xticlabels (i.e. "1:j", "2:j", "3:j" in the link above).

I tried:

```
set xtic font ',12'
```

but it only makes the xtic labels bigger.

I also tried:

```
set style histogram rowstacked title offset 0,-1 font ',12'
```

and again, didn't notice any change.

Any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use enhanced text syntax to change the font size of these labels:

With

```
set termoption enhanced
plot ...,\
    newhistogram "{/*1.2 title}",\
```

you can increase the font size by 20%. To set an absolute font size, use the syntax `{/=14 title}`.